# Heteroscedasticity due to skewness of predictor(s)

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, skewness

I read that in a linear model skewness of one of the independent variables can be the reason for heteroscedasticity in the model but I can't think of (or create) an example where this would be the case, i.e. where $Y = X \beta + u$ with $u \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ but where a Goldfeld-Quandt test would (correctly) detect heteroscedasticity. What would be such an example or is the initial statement incorrect?

Comment: Reference? This does not make sense to me from a statistical standpoint. The unequal variance has to do with the error term, which will be the error, even if you use a designed experiment to pick observations from the skewed variable.

Comment: I read it here: https://itfeature.com/correlation-and-regression-analysis/introduction-reasons-and-consequences-of-heteroscedasticity
Point 6 states that skewness in the predictors might lead to heteroscedasticity.

Comment: That material is simply incorrect. No surprise, there is plenty of bogus "information" on the internet.